# Continue the Pattern of Circles

Tags: geometry, pattern

The following shapes are sequenced from left to right. Describe or create the next five shapes. Bonus points to those who describe how the pattern works.

[image]

- The pattern could continue on forever.
- The line thicknesses you see here are 1, 3, and 5; and the next five shapes require only these.

Spoilers: [I presented this as a programming question and folks made some very cool animations.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/41901/numbers-as-circular-graphics)

Comment: I would expect that once you can create the next five shapes, you'd also be able to describe the pattern, so I'm not sure why thats bonus points.

Comment: Nice puzzle. I like the idea. Florian solved it too fast though, didn't get a chance to get cracking ;c)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here is your sequence:

> [image: Sequence]

And the explanation is:

> These are Roman numerals.  Read the circles from inside out.  Thickness 1 is I, thickness 3 is V, thickness 5 is X.

Comment: How many seconds of looking at it did it take you to crack it?

Comment: Not many.  It now feels like the pattern popped up almost immediately, as soon as I saw the 1,2,3 at the left.  But I was bothered by the 5th symbol that didn't fit and I rejected the solution for a while.  Writing a little program to generate the image was the longest of course.