# Continue the Pattern #6 Fractions of Circles

Tags: pattern

Can you find the continuation of the following pattern?
[image: Circles of fractions]

For a hint I added a Title.

Comment: I want to say "B with the 1 o'clock and 2 o'clock pieces inverted". It would make perfect sense! Rot13(Ebgngr svefg ebj pybpxjvfr naq nqq vg gb frpbaq ebj)

Comment: @jafe: Hi. Why are you relating it to a clock?

Comment: Just didn't know how else to call them, since "upper right" is ambiguous :)

Comment: @jafe. The pattern you described is not the one I intended, but I must say I also don't see the one you suggest. Do you mind being a slight bit more specific: are you following it vertically or horizontally? The one I intended works both ways...

Comment: To avoid confusion, this puzzle is not the same as [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5573/continue-the-pattern-of-circles?rq=1).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If we consider them to be

> binary we get $1/1 + 0/1 = 1/1$, $1/2 + 1/3 = 5/6$. Lastly, we have $3/2 + 1/3 = 11/6$ which corresponds to B.

Here is an image

> [image]

Comment: $(+1)$ This *has* to be the answer :D